# Is there a vectorization method to mitigate slow-execution time for converting images into arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, conv-neural-network, vectorization, glob

I am creating a CNN project that requires accessing several images in a file. While successful, one problem with my model code is that the execution-rate is very slow, especially when implemented in my project.

I have looked up vectorization methods to increase the speed of changing each image in a list into an array but remained unsuccessful.

The dataset contains 510 images. When an image in that dataset is printed out, the file path is printed out rather than arrays.

Here is a very small portion of my code:

```
# Necessary imports (simplified)
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import tensorflow as tf

# Data science imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

# File handling
import glob

file_path = "dataverse_files/MiMM_SBILab Dataset/"
path2files = glob.glob(file_path+"*.bmp")

X = path2files
y = []

for i in range(len(X)):
    X[i] = mpimg.imread(X[i])  # Slow execution rate
    y.append(i)
    
print(X[0:5])
print(y[0:5])
```

If you have any questions or need clarification, please do not hesitate to comment. Thanks in advance!